# Looking for some constructive criticism

Tags: discussion

Why did my answer to this question: [How to get Wii U to connect to SOCKS5 proxy?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/281766/how-to-get-wii-u-to-connect-to-socks5-proxy/281888#281888) get downvoted? I did proper research, provided a correct answer, and answered the OP's question. Did I miss something/do something wrong, or is it just that one person out of this whole site didn't fancy my response?

Comment: It looks ok to me.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but while the first part of you answer is good, the second part basically sums up to 'read this link' and 'visit this page'. Try to summarise the relevant parts of the info in the linked articles, or quote relevant snippets to save people a click & to prevent that info becoming lost should the links change or get taken down for whatever reason.

Comment: @Robotnik I normally would agree with you, and think that in general, you should summarize links, but in this case, these links provided _extra_ information, after I had answered the OP's question. Do you think I should go ahead and quote necessary info from those links, despite it not being directly pertinent to the question asked?

Comment: Your entire answer reads like, "Read these links here", which makes it much less useful.  If those links go down, now 75% of your answer is invalid.  When linking somewhere, summarizing the info isn't just useful, but almost guaranteed necessary.

Comment: @Frank Okay I edited it, it should be better now